# Counting number of pixels with unique band values

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an image with 3 bands. I would like to count the number of pixels with unique band-value-combinations.

Example:

```
PIXELS       BAND1       BAND2       BAND3
pixel_1      22          17          1
pixel_2      12           6          1
pixel_3      12           6          1
pixel_4      56          17          4
pixel_5      9           17          2
pixel_6      22          17          1
pixel_7      22          17          1
```

The result here should be 4.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your image into an array image and reduce region with a `countDistinct()` reducer.

```
// Dummy setup, since you didn't provide a functioning script
var scale = 30
var region = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]).buffer(90).bounds()
var image = ee.Image([
  ee.Image.random(0).multiply(2).round().int8().rename('band1'),
  ee.Image.random(1).multiply(2).round().int8().rename('band2'),
  ee.Image.random(2).multiply(2).round().int8().rename('band3'),
]).reproject('EPSG:4326', null, scale).clip(region)


var count = image
  .toArray()
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countDistinct(),
    geometry: region, 
    scale: scale
  }).get('array')

print(count)
Map.addLayer(image, {min: 0, max: 2})
Map.centerObject(region)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb7a6c1cdd2368c655621db0259242c8

Comment: Hi Daniel, it works flawlessly, thank you so much!!